# Dynamic Update Postgres Queries

Tags: javascript, postgresql, pg-promise

Is it possible for a single API PUT endpoint to use dynamic UPDATE/INSERT queries?

Example:
We have a patient table `patient` that has a `first_name` and `last_name` column. Sometimes we want to update the first name for a patient using a PUT http request but other times we want to update both `first_name` and `last_name` using that same PUT http request.

The first update query would like this:

```
UPDATE patient
SET first_name = "new first name"
WHERE id = 1
```

The second query would like this:

```
UPDATE patient
SET 
first_name = "new first name",
last_name = "new last name"
WHERE id = 1
```

We would like to combine this query to support both use cases without having to do a bunch of js gymnastics to inject sql into the query. We use pg-promise to support our psql/express integration.

Comment: http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.update

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **COALESCE** function.

```
UPDATE patient
SET 
first_name = COALESCE(<new first name>,first_name),
last_name = COALESCE(<new last name>,last_name)
WHERE id = 1
```

COALESCE returns the first non-null value it encounters. So if your **new last name** is null, it will preserve the original value of the column and likewise.

Comment: Hello thank you for answering my question. This is a step in the right direction, however what if I want to set a column to null?

Answer (score 1):

Your last comment indicates you may want to use NULL to two diametrically opposed purposes, **you cannot do that**. It would seem you have two options:

- Write separate queries, invoking the one(s) necessary.
- Designate a dummy string value that essentially says *set the corresponding column to NULL*.
  Assuming you want to avoid separate queries try something like: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/BTlehu61))

```
update patient 
   set first_name = nullif(coalesce(<new first name>,first_name), '<string meaning set to null>') 
     , last_name  = nullif(coalesce(<new last name> ,last_name),'<string meaning set to null>')
 where id = id_in;
```

The above uses the [nullif()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF) function to test the resulting value from `coalesce()` for a specific value. If those values match the result of the expression is NULL.